# In Playwright,cannot keep Page.on listening cause connection closed?

Tags: python, playwright, pyspider

I am trying to use Playwright to listen event in browser continuously,but it seems that if I don't use browser.close(),it cannot keep listening either.

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.on('response', on_response)
    page.goto('https://sport.dgut.edu.cn')
```

after running this, Playwright exit automatically.
if I swap page.on and page.goto,it will like this:

```
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=Error('Connection closed')>
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Connection closed
```

Comment: What's the definition for `on_response` and what are you really trying to accomplish here? Usually, if you're trying to wait for a particular response, you'd use `page.expect_response`.